# Duplicate Elimination c++ using unique_copy Algorithm (Exercise 16.9)

Tags: c++, algorithm, duplicates

I tried to create the duplicate elimination exercise using unique_copy algorithm. I need to enter 20 integers into an empty vector. However, the output said all zeros (0 0 0 ... 0 0 0) in the vector. What should I do so that I can find the unique variables in the vector using unique_copy algorithm? Exercise 16.9 of the textbook (*C++ How to Program 9th Edition*) says, "Use a back_inserter to enable the vector to grow as new items are added. Use the copy algorithm to display the unique values." (738)
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int, allocator<int> > vec_t;
typedef insert_iterator<vec_t> vec_iter;
typedef ostream_iterator<int, char, char_traits<char> > os_iter;

int main()
{
   int SIZE = 20;
   int twenty[20] = {};
   vec_t v20(twenty, twenty + 20);
   int entry;
   int current_index = 0;
   bool duplicated = false;
   for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter number: " << endl;
      cin >> entry;
      if(entry > 10 && entry < 100)
      {
         for(int u = 0; u < current_index; u++)
         {
             if(twenty[i] == entry)
             {
                cout << "You already entered these numbers " << endl;
                duplicated = true;
                break;
             }
         }
         if(duplicated == false)
         {
             twenty[current_index] = entry;
             current_index++;
         }
      }
      else
      {
          cout << "Error: invalid number; you must enter between 10 and 100 " << endl;
          i--;
      }
   }
   for(int x = 0; x < current_index; x++)
   {
      cout << twenty[x] << endl;
      vec_t outcome;
      vec_iter ins (outcome, outcome.begin());
      cout << "Vector: " << endl << " ";
      copy(v20.cbegin(), v20.cend(), os_iter(cout, " "));
      cout << endl;
      unique_copy(v20.cbegin(), v20.cend(), ins);
      cout << endl << "After unique_copy, outcome contains ";
      copy(outcome.cbegin(), outcome.cend(), os_iter(cout, " "));
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I hope you will help me solve problems.
ChonglinXu

Comment: `i <= SIZE` accesses your array out of bounds. `if(twenty[i] == entry)` makes no sense in a loop using `u` as an index. It's not exactly clear what all of your strange initialization is meant to do. Start simple, delete this code, initialize an array or vector with 20 ints that will allow you to see if/how the algorithm works, and apply the algorithm to them. You should also read the documentation so you know what the algorithm is meant to do. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy

Comment: I see values being loaded into `twenty` but I do not see them being transferred into `vec20` for use in the remainder of the program.

Comment: https://ideone.com/71wrNH